# How to find out what libraries are linked to an existing executable and appropriately re-link and re-compile the code?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++, ld

I want to use the Dynamic Control Flow Graph tool in PinPlay kit. In the package, I have the `dcfg-reader.cpp` file that implements a sample code to use the DCFG API, and also I can find the executable file named `dcfg-reader` which is pre-compiled. I want to change the code in a way to extract my desired information. Now, I do not know how this code should be compiled, for example what libraries are needed to be linked. The developers just have mentioned to link two specific libraries (named `libdcfg-pinplay.a` and `libintelzipstream.a`).

Here you can see some parts of the `dcfl-reader.cpp` code and the main function:

```cpp
#include "dcfg_api.H"
#include "dcfg_trace_api.H"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace dcfg_api;
using namespace dcfg_trace_api;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    cout << "This file is edited!" << endl;
    if (argc < 2)
        usage(argv[0]);

    parse_args(argc, argv);

    if (!dcfg_file)
    {
        cerr << "Missing dcfg file. " << endl;
        usage(argv[0]);
    }
    // Make a new DCFG object.
    DCFG_DATA* dcfg = DCFG_DATA::new_dcfg();


    // Read from file.
    cerr << "Reading DCFG from '" << dcfg_file << "'..." << endl;
    string errMsg;
    if (!dcfg->read(dcfg_file, errMsg)) {
        cerr << "error: " << errMsg << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // write some summary data from DCFG.
    summarizeDcfg(dcfg);

    // Second argument should be a DCFG-trace file.
    if (edge_file) {
        summarizeTrace(dcfg, edge_file);
    }

    // free memory.
    delete dcfg;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: `dcfg_api.H` and `dcfg_trace_api.H` files are in the `include/` directory.

I use the `ldd` command in order to find the shared libraries linked to this executable and this is the output:

```
 ldd bin/intel64/dcfg-reader 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffec59b3000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f9d7c6bb000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9d7c4a1000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9d7c115000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9d7be0b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9d7bbf3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9d7b829000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556d2b779000)
```

Based on this information, I use this command to re-compile the code:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -static -I include/ examples/dcfg-reader.cpp -L lib/intel64/ -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -l dcfg-pinplay -l intelzipstream -lm -lbz2 -lz -o out-dcfg-reader
```

But this results in a lot of `undefined references` which means the right libraries are not linked. Here you can see some parts of the output:

```
lib/intel64//libdcfg-pinplay.a(DcfgData.o): In function `std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_unshift() [clone .part.109]':
DcfgData.cpp:(.text+0x6be): undefined reference to `std::_Filebuf_base::_M_write(char*, long)'
lib/intel64//libdcfg-pinplay.a(DcfgData.o): In function `char* std::priv::__write_integer_backward<unsigned long>(char*, int, unsigned long) [clone .part.570]':
DcfgData.cpp:(.text+0x8a1): undefined reference to `std::priv::__hex_char_table_lo()'
DcfgData.cpp:(.text+0x8f1): undefined reference to `std::priv::__hex_char_table_hi()'
lib/intel64//libdcfg-pinplay.a(DcfgData.o): In function `std::priv::_Slist_base<std::pair<unsigned long const, Dcfg::MtCounts>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, Dcfg::MtCounts> > >::_M_erase_after(std::priv::_Slist_node_base*, std::priv::_Slist_node_base*) [clone .isra.520] [clone .constprop.919]':
DcfgData.cpp:(.text+0xfd4): undefined reference to `std::__malloc_alloc::deallocate(void*, unsigned long)'
DcfgData.cpp:(.text+0xfe4): undefined reference to `std::__malloc_alloc::deallocate(void*, unsigned long)'
.
.
.
intel_bzip_ostream.cpp:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
lib/intel64//libintelzipstream.a(intel_gzip_ostream.o): In function `intel_gzip_ostreambuf::~intel_gzip_ostreambuf()':
intel_gzip_ostream.cpp:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `std::__malloc_alloc::deallocate(void*, unsigned long)'
lib/intel64//libintelzipstream.a(intel_gzip_ostream.o): In function `intel_gzip_ostreambuf::intel_gzip_ostreambuf(std::string const&, int)':
intel_gzip_ostream.cpp:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `std::__malloc_alloc::allocate(unsigned long)'
intel_gzip_ostream.cpp:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
lib/intel64//libintelzipstream.a(intel_bzip_istream.o): In function `intel_bzip_istreambuf::~intel_bzip_istreambuf()':
intel_bzip_istream.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `std::__malloc_alloc::deallocate(void*, unsigned long)'
lib/intel64//libintelzipstream.a(intel_bzip_istream.o): In function `intel_bzip_istreambuf::intel_bzip_istreambuf(std::string const&, int)':
intel_bzip_istream.cpp:(.text+0x2bb): undefined reference to `std::__malloc_alloc::allocate(unsigned long)'
intel_bzip_istream.cpp:(.text+0x2e0): undefined reference to `std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
lib/intel64//libintelzipstream.a(intel_gzip_istream.o): In function `intel_gzip_istreambuf::~intel_gzip_istreambuf()':
intel_gzip_istream.cpp:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `std::__malloc_alloc::deallocate(void*, unsigned long)'
lib/intel64//libintelzipstream.a(intel_gzip_istream.o): In function `intel_gzip_istreambuf::intel_gzip_istreambuf(std::string const&, int)':
intel_gzip_istream.cpp:(.text+0x24b): undefined reference to `std::__malloc_alloc::allocate(unsigned long)'
intel_gzip_istream.cpp:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to `std::__stl_throw_length_error(char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So my question is that how can I hack this problem and get the code compiled correctly. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a documentation from the developers explaining how to compile.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the `undefined` references occurring at compile time or runtime? Also, as a rule, when `g++` is your compiler, you don't need to explicitly link `libgcc_s`, `libc` or `libstdc++`; GCC in general links the former two when necessary, and `g++` specifically implicitly links the third.

Comment: at the compile time.

Comment: Try removing the `-lgcc_s`, `-lc` and `-lstdc++`; none of those need to be explicitly linked (`g++` does it automatically as needed). Then try rerunning the compile, and edit your question to add in at least the first dozen or so lines of undefined reference output, so we have an idea what it's failing to find; a [MCVE] needs to include enough of the output/error info to guide us, so we're not trying to replicate your setup from scratch.

Comment: Now I have added a small part of the output after removing `-lc` and `-lstdc++`.

Comment: Have you read the [PinPlay installation instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/program-recordreplay-toolkit#installation)? It looks like it does include information on building; it comes with a `Makefile` that should do all the work for you.